# How do I find top most used words by some kind of formula with another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is like this:

```
id `  text                             c1
1     Hello world how are you people    1 
2     Hello people I am fine  people    1
3     Good Morning people               0
4     Good Evening                      0
```

Now I want to find top most frequently word used in a different way, let me explain.

Let me show you the expected output first, then I will explain:

```
Hello - 2
People - 1
world - 1
how - 1
are - 1
you - 1
I - 1
am - 1
fine - 1
```

What i am trying to say is: Here `people` is in 3 rows 3 times. But the count is shown only 1 in output. Because:

row 1 contain `people` and `c1` = 1
row 2 contain `people` and `c1` = 1
row 3 contain `people` and `c1` = 0

So row1 + row2 - row3 = 1 (because value of row1 and row2 are 1, and row3 is 0)

In the same way, `Hello`'s value is 2 in output, because

row 1 contain `hello` and `c1` = 1
row 2 contain `hello` and `c1` = 1

So row1 + row2 = 2

I do not want to create a new column of output, just want to print it.

I am using this to count most used words

`print(pd.Series(' '.join(df['text']).lower().split()).value_counts()[:10])`

But idk how to calculate things in my way

Comment: For `people` 1+1-0 =1. How? It should be `2`

Comment: I don't want to add `c1`, because c1 is 0, people get one negative point.

Comment: So you want to check if word has appeared in a row, then you add a point if `c1` is 1 else you subtract. Right?

Comment: Yeah. People appear 2 times when `c1` is 1, so it gets 2 points. But then 1 point get substracted, because `c1` is 0.

Comment: Do you know the answer bro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for storage values - first zip column with `ci`, loop them with [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and add if `c1 == 0` add negative counts.

Last filter only positive or `0` counts in dictionary comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

zipped = zip(df['text'], df['c1'])
d = defaultdict(int)

for a, b in zipped:
    c = Counter(set(a.lower().split()))
    for k, v in c.items():
        if b == 0:
            v = -v
        d[k] += v

d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v > 0}  
print (d)
{'are': 1, 'hello': 2, 'how': 1,'people': 1, 'world': 1, 'you': 1, 'i': 1, 'am': 1, 'fine': 1}
```

Similar solution if value in `c1` are sorted - first all `1` and then all `0`:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

df = df.sort_values('c1', ascending=False)

zipped = zip(df['text'], df['c1'])
d = defaultdict(int)

for a, b in zipped:
    c = Counter(set(a.lower().split()))
    for k, v in c.items():
        if (b == 0) and (k in d):
            d[k] -= v
        elif (b == 1):
            d[k] += v

print (d)

defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'are': 1, 'hello': 2, 'how': 1, 'people': 1, 
                            'world': 1, 'you': 1, 'i': 1, 'am': 1, 'fine': 1})
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': list(d.keys()), 
                   'No': list(d.values())}).sort_values('No', ascending=False)
print (df)
      val  No
1   hello   2
0     are   1
2     how   1
3  people   1
4   world   1
5     you   1
6       i   1
7      am   1
8    fine   1
```

---

```
s = pd.Series(d).sort_values(ascending=False)
print (s)
hello     2
fine      1
am        1
i         1
you       1
world     1
people    1
how       1
are       1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you also tell me, how to sort `d` by `value` and print?

Comment: @johndoe - Sure, do you need output in Series?

Comment: Series would be better, but this is also good. I just want to see and analyze them

Comment: @johndoe - Or 2 column DataFrame?